# Adressing PHP array decoded from JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm loading a JSON array and decode it to an PHP array

```
$jsonfile = file_get_contents('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=15min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo'); 
$jsonarray = json_decode($jsonfile); 
var_dump($jsonarray);
```

So far so good I get an array that looks like that:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { 
    ["Meta Data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { 
        ["1. Information"]=> string(49) "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes" 
        ["2. Symbol"]=> string(5) "AAWVX" 
        ["3. Last Refreshed"]=> string(10) "2017-06-30" 
        ["4. Output Size"]=> string(9) "Full size" 
        ["5. Time Zone"]=> string(10) "US/Eastern" 
    } 
    ["Time Series (Daily)"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (105) { 
        ["2017-06-30"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (5) { 
            ["1. open"]=> string(7) "10.5100" 
            ["2. high"]=> string(7) "10.5100" 
            ["3. low"]=> string(7) "10.5100" 
            ["4. close"]=> string(7) "10.5100" 
            ["5. volume"]=> string(1) "0" 
        } 
        ["2017-06-29"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (5) { ["1. open"]=> string(7) "10.4800" ["2. high"]=> string(7) "10.4800" ["3. low"]=> string(7) "10.4800" ["4. close"]=> string(7) "10.4800" ["5. volume"]=> string(1) "0" } 
        ["2017-06-28"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (5) { ["1. open"]=> string(7) "10.5600" ["2. high"]=> string(7) "10.5600" ["3. low"]=> string(7) "10.5600" ["4. close"]=> string(7) "10.5600" ["5. volume"]=> string(1) "0" } ...
```

But when I try to adress the array like

```
var_dump($jsonarray['Meta Data']);
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Either decode with `true` as second arg or use `$jsonarray->{'Meta Data'}->{'1. Information'}`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php  See the second argument to the function. Looks like you need it to be true.

Comment: @Jay there's a timer before you can accept an answer.

Comment: I know, I was just looking at your track record.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because `json_decode()` with no parameters attempts to convert your json string to an stdClass object. If you want to convert it to an array, you need to set the 2nd parameters (the `$assoc` boolean) to `true`:

```
$json = file_get_contents('LINK TO JSON OUTPUT'); 
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```