# Modify JSON Feed With php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON Feed which is accessed by an api.
The json feed it returns is as below:

```
[  
   {  
      "isoDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00.0000000",
      "events":[  
         {  
            "id":"-7317",
            "name":"Exhibition SKMU: The collection 2015-2017",
         },
         {  
            "id":"-91417",
            "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo",
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "isoDate":"2017-09-16T00:00:00.0000000",
      "events":[  
         {  
            "id":"-7317",
            "name":"Exhibition SKMU: The collection 2015-2017",
         },
         {  
            "id":"-91417",
            "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo",
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need the isoDate to be listed with each event instead of individually.
e.g.

```
[  
   {  
      "events":[  
         {  
            "isoDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00.0000000",
            "id":"-7317",
            "name":"Exhibition SKMU: The collection 2015-2017",
         },
         {  
            "isoDate":"2017-09-15T00:00:00.0000000",
            "id":"-91417",
            "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo",
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "events":[  
         {  
            "isoDate":"2017-09-16T00:00:00.0000000",
            "id":"-7317",
            "name":"Exhibition SKMU: The collection 2015-2017",
         },
         {  
            "isoDate":"2017-09-16T00:00:00.0000000",
            "id":"-91417",
            "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo",
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can this be achieved with php? Basically fetch that feed from a url and then display it in my preferred format?

Comment: yes can, you must decode that json first to get the array, after that you can try to loop that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what you have to do, to get back your desired format of the json,
`$json` is your json string:

```
$eventList = json_decode($json);

foreach($eventList as $eventEntry){
    $isoDate = $eventEntry->isoDate;

    foreach($eventEntry->events as $subEventEntry){
        $subEventEntry->isoDate = $isoDate;
    }

    //delete the isoDate from outer
    unset($eventEntry->isoDate);
}

echo json_encode($eventList);
```

So basically, you are first decoding your json into php structure, apply your changes and after that, encode it back. Note here, that I have not appened `true` as second parameter for the `$json_decode`, but working with the resulting object.

**Also**: Your json is not standard comform and could result in errors. PHP will properly not decode it, because your object end with a comma. The last element of an object should be without comma. Instead of

```
{  
    "id":"-91417",
    "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo",
}
```

make it like this:

```
{  
    "id":"-91417",
    "name":"Torget - a multi cultural meeting place in Geilo"
}
```

I know, this can be a problem, when you get it from an API, but this is another problem of itself...

**EDIT:**

To get every "events" into one big array, you have to store them just like your imagination ;) . Think it like this: `$subEventEntry` holds one "events"-object. Because you are iterating both levels, you see everyone object of them. My suggestion would be to store them in a new array, and recreating the structure around it:

```
$everything = new stdClass();
$everything->events = array();
```

and then, in the inner loop:

```
foreach($eventList as $eventEntry){
    $isoDate = $eventEntry->isoDate;

    foreach($eventEntry->events as $subEventEntry){
        $subEventEntry->isoDate = $isoDate;
        $everything->events[] = $subEventEntry; // <-- this has to be added
    }

    //delete the isoDate from outer
    unset($eventEntry->isoDate);
}
```

When recreating the structure, and you don't need the old structure anymore you could remove the `unset`.

Just remeber every `[ ]` pair in the json represents an array, every `{ }` pair an object (`stdClass`). The name of this object/array is referenced `->` by its class property in the superobject.

Comment: Thanks - that's working well - that json format was ok - i fotgot to remove those comma's when pasting here as there was alot of extra unecessary lines. Is it possible to combine all those events under the 1 events node:
"events":[

Comment: Yes, see my Edit.

Comment: Thanks - had been trying various things the gist of what you were doing but was getting array errors - working fine with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for example:

```
 $yourjson;/* your json */
 $events = json_decode($yourjson, true);
 foreach($events as $event){

 echo $event["isoDate"];
 }
```

Comment: You should add the `true` parameter to `json_decode()` so that it makes it a php array instead of an stdClass. `json_decode($yourjson,true)`. More information on this can be seen on my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893673/adressing-php-array-decoded-from-json/44893702#44893702

Comment: Actually, `stdClass` would be perfectly fine. Just remeber to modify the objects with `->`. After that you even can encode it back, having the same array/object structure.

Comment: @FabianN. yes that true

Comment: Don't be afraid of `stdClass`! Use it, it is there for a reason. See my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use json_decode to decode the json object to php array then modify the array and encode it using json_encode

Comment: this answer could be simplified : "yes" , or even "you could use php"

Comment: Because your answer doesn't actually explain anything.