# PHP json decode array reverse

Tags: php, json, array-reverse

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to reverse a `json_decode` using `array_reverse` but I'm getting the following error

> Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

**Using the code below:**

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$output = json_decode($data);

$output = array_reverse($output);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON data appears to consist of an object, not an array. Simple solution: Set the second parameter of json_decode to true.

Comment: have you tried `$output = (array)json_decode($data)`?

Comment: json_decode($data, true);

Comment: $output = json_decode($data, true); https://prnt.sc/pt9bd0

Comment: Maybe a better question might be WHY would you need to reverse the array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893673/adressing-php-array-decoded-from-json/44893702#44893702

Answer (score 3):

You have to put second parameter `true` in

```
$output = json_decode($data, true);
```

by default `json_decode` convert json to php-object, if you put true as parameter - it should convert it to array