# Is there a way to access a json object elements using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, post

I am trying to get a data from my own API using PHP  \
My PHP code :

```
$cart = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true));
foreach ($cart->thoubss as $a){
    echo($a['0']); // trying to get the first element in the array (4) in the first iteration and then (3) in the second iteration
    echo($a['1']); // trying to get the first element in the array (5) in the first iteration and then (3) in the second iteration
}
```

My JSON input :
`{"thoubss":"{'0': [4, 5], '1': [5, 3]}"}`

I am getting
`PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

print_r($cart) output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [thoubss
] => {'0': [
        4,
        5
    ], '1': [
        5,
        3
    ]
}
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893702/5827005

Comment: `{"thoubss":"{'0': [4, 5], '1': [5, 3]}"}` input has `thoubss` key which contains a string `{'0': [4, 5], '1': [5, 3]}`. You can't supply a string for `foreach()`.

Comment: `print_r($cart)` output you posted doesn't match your JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    $cart = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true),true);
```

json_decode will return an array instead of an stdClass object

Comment: I am still getting (PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach())

Comment: In your specific case and after adding the second argument to json_decode try replacing $cart->thoubss by $cart['thoubss']

Comment: I modified it to $cart = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true),true);
and foreach ($cart['thoubss'] as $a){ echo($a['0']); } but still getting the same error

Comment: @NicolasF I guess you didn't tested your code with OP's JSON input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method also.

```
$cart = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input",true),true);
```

This will return an array like below.

```
$cart = array(
    "thoubss" => array(
        '0' => array(4, 5),
        '1' => array(5, 3)
    )
);
```

Now you can use like below:

```
foreach ($cart['thoubss'] as $a){
    echo $a[0];
    echo $a[1];
}
```

Comment: I copied and paste your code and still getting PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Print your `$cart` variable to check whether it is returning an array or not.

Comment: @SureshChand I guess you didn't tested your code with OP's JSON input string.

Comment: @SureshChand  Array
(
    [thoubss
] => {'0': [
        1,
        1
    ], '1': [
        1,
        1
    ]
}
)